How to automatically retrieve a ZonedDateTime/OffsetDateTime based on the connection time zone in Spring Boot?
Background
I have a MySQL 8 server with default-time-zone set to +08:00, with existing dates store using the DATETIME type.
I want to use Spring Data JPA to retrieve the date into a ZonedDateTime, e.g. 2024-07-08T08:00:00+08:00 or 2024-07-08T00:00:00Z. And eventually send this date time to the frontend for clients to determine how to render based on their time zones.
App servers are running in the cloud. TZ env vars are currently misconfigured I believe. Some servers are unset, some set to "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur".
I figured I have to set the serverTimeZone in JDBC connection string and TZ correctly. But I kept getting wrong output. For example 2024-07-08T08:00:00 viewed in DBeaver is returned as 2024-07-08T08:00:00Z from Spring Boot.
The closest thing I came to is by setting both JDBC and TZ to "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur", and convert using ZoneId.systemDefault(). If possible, I want to achieve this without adding a converter to all my entities.
Question
How to automatically retrieve a ZonedDateTime/OffsetDateTime based on the connection time zone in Spring Boot?

The only really problematic area would be if the clock is set wrongly anywhere. Is it?

I have control to set the TZ correctly since it's running in a container. If I set them to "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur", everything runs fine. It's just that I'm looking for a scalable way to convert the date times into UTC so that the API consumer can determine what to render.

Avoid defaults

MySQL 8 server with default-time-zone

You should not need a default time zone to be set. Write your code to specify explicitly your desired/expected time zone. Don't let your Java code break just because some sysadmin/DBA changed a default setting.

TZ env vars are currently misconfigured I believe

Good example of why you should not rely on such defaults. Notice how the code below works without regard to default time zone in host OS or in database server.

The closest thing I came to is by setting both JDBC and TZ to "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur", and convert using ZoneId.systemDefault().

If you want the time zone Asia/Kuala_Lumpur, pass a ZoneId object for Asia/Kuala_Lumpur. Do not depend on defaults.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur" ) ;

Offset versus time zone

default-time-zone set to +08:00

+08:00 is an offset, not a time zone.

OffsetAn offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the temporal meridian of UTC.
Time ZoneA time zone is much more. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

SQL standard uses offsets, not time zones

Spring Data JPA to retrieve the date into a ZonedDateTime

You cannot do this directly. The SQL standard does not support time zones, only offsets. The SQL standard type names TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE & TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE are misnomers.
OffsetDateTime
In the database, store a moment (a point on the timeline) in a type akin to the SQL standard data type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. JDBC maps that to the Java type java.time.OffsetDateTime.
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;

Use java.time.Instant generally, to represent a moment

And eventually send this date time to the frontend for clients to determine how to render based on their time zones.

Good idea, generally. Instant is the basic building block of the java.time framework.
Pass an Instant object, a moment as seen with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.
You should generally represent a moment using Instant. Unfortunately JDBC does not map to that type. You can easily convert.
Instant instant = myOffsetDateTime.toInstant() ;           // From `OffsetDateTime` to `Instant`.
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // From `Instant` to `OffsetDateTime`. 

Some JDBC drivers do support writing & retrieving an Instant, but that is not portable code as JDBC does not require support for that type.
ZonedDateTime
The receiving programmer can adjust to a time zone by applying a ZoneId to get a ZonedDateTime. Specify a real time zone name in format of Continent/Region.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;

Correct clock on server
While you can, and should, ignore the default time zone of the host OS and the database server, you do have to rely upon the hardware clock of the computer being set to proper time.
If that clock is wrong, then your app breaks. If you cannot trust the host clock, call upon a trusted time server.

I want to avoid specifying timezone in the code at all, so that we can scale to other time zones as well. My problem is that the MySQL server were set to +08:00 in the early days, and all date times in the database were assumed to +08:00. I do have control on the app servers to set TZ correctly, that's why I think using ZoneId.systemDefault may help. i.e Getting OffsetDateTime, convert to systemDefault, then to UTC, then return to API consumer. I'm looking for a scalable way to do this as this quite a huge project.

"all date times in the database were assumed to +08:00" — Do you mean the column was defined as DATETIME (equivalent to SQL standard type TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE) rather than as TIMESTAMP (equivalent to SQL standard type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) in MySQL?  (See doc) Then you have a mess on your hand. You should have explained this in your Question. This is an XY Question, where you should be asking how to clean up this mess.

You are right, all are in DATETIME type when I inherited the project. I understand that DATETIME will just store whatever we input. I supposed the DBA valued readability from MySQL client. I was hoping JDBC or Hibernate could automagically convert to a Zoned/OffsetDateTime based on the connection time zone. I guess my last resort is to do a migration and convert all the DATETIME in DB into UTC

I happened to stumble upon @TimeZoneStorage which correctly set the ZonedDateTime based on the JVM time zone.
@Entity
class Something {
  @TimeZoneStorage(TimeZoneStorageType.NORMALIZE)
  private ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime;
}

For e.g. a DATETIME MySQL type with value 2024-07-05T13:00:00 will set the zonedDateTime to 2024-07-05T05:00:00Z when running with TZ=UTC
Likewise, in TZ=Asia/Kuala_Lumpur will become 2024-07-05T13:00:00+08:00
Setting hibernate.timezone.default_storage=NORMALIZE should work the same.
This should temporarily solve my issue. In retrospective, this looks like a remnant of upgrading Spring Boot 2.x to 3.x
A better solution perhaps is to set MySQL time zone back to UTC, and do a migration to convert all the DATETIME data into UTC.
[Ref]
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#ddl-timezones
